# Unable to logout of Yii app & force page to redirect (Yii 1.x)

Tags: php, session, yii, yii-cactiverecord

I'm trying to get my Yii app to auto logout after a set number of seconds when a particular type of user is logged in.

I have made the following amends to my protected/components/WebUser.php file:

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();

    if (($user = $this->getState('userModel')) !== null) {
        $this->setUserData(unserialize($user));

        if ($this->isNonAdminUser()) {
            $this->authTimeout = 3600; // 1 hour timeout
        }
    }

    $this->updateAuthStatus();
}

// function automatically directly after $this->logout()
protected function afterLogout() {
    Yii::app()->request->redirect(('site/front/login'));

    //Yii::app()->request->redirect((Yii::app()->user->returnUrl));
}
```

This will basically logout a 'non admin user' out of the session after 1 hour of no activity - this works however I'd like to be able to 'force' them back to the homepage as well. I've tried to use the redirect function in the afterLogout() but it doesn't seem to do a redirect for some reason?

Any ideas why not?

Note - I am using Yii 1.x

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `afterLogout()` was really called? Besides that, the `returnUrl` would be the last page viewed not the homepage.

Comment: good call with the returnUrl stuff. It all logs out and it does hit the afterLogout() as i've put in a random path in the redirect however i'd like to tell my app to automatically redirect back to redirect url if possible.

Note - the logging out is all fine, once the time expires if I press F5 and reload the page I am logged out and redirected - I am just trying to take out the manual element of me pressing reload (if possible)

Comment: Ah okay I see. That's only possible with the help of javascript and ajax. Basically you set a timer to call a function after 3600 sec which checks if the user should be logged out. If so do a location redirect in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Yii::app()->user->homeUrl` instead of `Yii::app()->user->returnUrl` inside `afterLogout` function.